# relocated the value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have df the part of information separt in 2 rows, some time i have 2 value for gender

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| Jon | 20 |
| male |  |
| sam | 21 |
| male |  |
| male |  |

i need move the gender to new column after age and remove the value from df, , some time i have 2 value for gender, i need keep one only

i try to pull the data using dplyr

Comment: Are the blanks in age truly blank character values (`""`) or are they represented as `NA`? Could you share the output of `dput(your_data)`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
df %>% 
  # create `gender` column selecting the value following a *proper* name,
  # i.e., a name that is *not* "male" or "female":
  mutate(gender = ifelse(lead(name) %in% c("male", "female"), lead(name), NA)) %>%
  # remove now-obsolete rows:
  filter(!name %in% c("male", "female"))
  name age gender
1 John  20   male
2  sam  21   male
```

If you have a "diverse" gender value in your data, just include it here:

`%in% c("male", "female", "diverse")`

Comment: thanks, what if i have in gender alot of type. lets say 500 type. did we can do by location of rows ?

Comment: I guess you mean you have 500 gender *values* or *tokens* (I can't assume you have 500 *types*). Apart from that, what do you mean by "did we can do by location of rows"?

Comment: the data above just example, what if use str_detect with case_when ?

Comment: Sure, if you have variants of "male", e.g. "Male" or "mal" etc. you can `str_detect`